# How to store JSONArray Response in cache memory with volley library?

Tags: android, json, performance, caching, android-volley

I don't show some code because I have no error. I know how to use Volley to store Bitmap / ImageView in cache memory. I tried to do the same but for text. I need to save my json in cache memory. I download my json from server. It works ! But What I need to do to save it in cache memory ?

Here is my function who return my json :

```
    public void getJSONObjectFromServer(String url, Context context) {
    RequestQueue        myRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    final Map<String, String>   mapArray = new HashMap<String, String>();

    JsonArrayRequest myJsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.i("ARRAY RESPONSE", response.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject myResult = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator<?> keys = myResult.keys();
                        while (keys.hasNext()) {
                            String keyDynamicValue = (String)keys.next();
                            String currentDynamicValue = myResult.getString(keyDynamicValue);
                            mapArray.put(keyDynamicValue, currentDynamicValue);
                            Log.i("[" + keyDynamicValue + "] =", currentDynamicValue);
                        }
                    Log.i("JSONOBJECT MYRESULT " + i, myResult.toString());     
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    myRequestQueue.add(myJsonArray);
}
}
```

I searched on multiple links but they are all to store Bitmap. Anybody has an idea of how I can do it ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For original volley, they rely on http response headers(such as Cache-Control, Date, Expires, ETag) to cache, it's hard to control on client. in my experience, except bitmap, the text response is really not need to cache in the memory, because that needn't fetch as quick as bitmap, therefore either volley and me, we didn't offer the cache for common request. I have a project calls [Netroid](https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid), it based on volley, in previous version, I achieved storing common text-based response into memory cache, after that, I realize common request delay was acceptable rather bitmap delay was no, so I rollback to original volley implementation.

My project has more features than volley, you can control the DiskBaseCache every response entry's expire time instead depend on response headers, and more powerful executing status callback like onCache(), onSuccess(), onFailure(), onFinish(), I shall glad if you'd enjoy it.